# How to apply a Stokes-law type drag correlation to simulate particle transport?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, drag, viscosity

I am implementing a model to simulate the (two-way coupled) transport of particles in a fluid. The flow field is being solved by a numerical solver for the Navier-Stokes equations (in this case using the Lattice-Boltzmann method).

I want to compute the drag force on the particles using Stokes law:

$$F_d=3\pi\mu D(\vec{u_f} - \vec{u_p})$$

where $\vec{u_f}$ is the fluid velocity and $\vec{u_p}$ that of the particle. My question is: where should I evaluate $\vec{u_f}$?

I find many models described in the literature which interpolate the fluid velocity field to the current location of the particle. However, that seems strange to me: isn't Stokes law based on the free-stream velocity far away from the particle?